# PayPal Hosted Pro Direct Payment

Tags: paypal

someone can help. I using PayPals Rest API to make a direct payment. I have a Pro account. The response, I get back from paypal after the autho process, has a status. PayPals documentation says there are 5 different statues that can be returned. (created; approved; failed; canceled; expired ). So my question is, if the status is pending, how can i know if at a latter date the payment has been successful or declined. There is no mention in the documentation to use an IPN. I cant find any documentation on these statues. Any help would really be appreciated.

Comment: Do you have your intent set to Sale or Authorization. If you have your intent set to authorization the payment can be in a pending status until the payment is captured. [Making your first call Rest API PayPal Developer](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/integration/direct/make-your-first-call)

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [Look up a payment resource](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/api/#look-up-a-payment-resource) call to get details about payments that have not completed, such as payments that are created and approved, or if a payment has failed.